# Effective dimension of random matrix product shrinks linearly?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose $A_k$ is a product of $k$ independent $n\times n$ matrices with IID standard normal entries and $\sigma_i$ be $i$th singular value of $A_k$.

Define effective squared rank as

$$R(A)=\frac{\left(\sum_i\sigma_i^2\right)^2}{\sum_i \sigma_i^4}$$

The following gives an almost perfect fit

$$R(A_k)\approx \frac{n}{k+1}$$

Why?

```
n = 1000;
R2[mat_] := 
  With[{x = SingularValueList[mat]}, (Total[x^2]^2/Total[x^4])];
maxK = 6;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
observed = R2 /@ NestList[# . sample &, sample, maxK - 1];
projected = n/(1 + Range[1, maxK]) // N;
TableForm[{observed, projected}\[Transpose], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"observed", "projected"}}]
```

[image]

Repost from [mathoverflow.SE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451016/additivity-of-purity-of-random-matrix-products)

**Edit** density of $\sigma^2$ of $A_k$ is given for $k=1$ and $k=2$ in Eq 3.46, Eq 3.50 of Akemann/Kierburg [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5694.pdf)

Comment: Has the power of APL with the readability of APL.

Comment: @copper.hat  the readability is a bit awkward since syntax was invented in 1980, https://chat.openai.com/share/e6fa9a34-f97d-43fe-94e7-94a2a20bc567

Comment: (Very) Marginally related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1140427/27978.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation, I initially thought it was a generic Mathematica explanation.

Comment: @copper.hat this explanation was automatically generated. ChatGPT can do the reverse and generate Mathematica code from plain English, results are [pretty good](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2944810)